# Integration Socialite with Laravel 5.1 InvalidState issue

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

I have a problem when installing Socialite plugin on Laravel 5.1.

First I have this AuthCOntroller.php code:

```
 public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
 //notice we are not doing any validation, you should do it

    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    // stroing data to our use table and logging them in
    $data = [
        'name' => $user->getName(),
        'email' => $user->getEmail()
    ];

     // Here, check if the user already exists in your records

    $my_user = User::where('email','=', $user->getEmail())->first();
    if($my_user === null) {
            Auth::login(User::firstOrCreate($data));
    } else {
        Auth::login($my_user);
    }

    //after login redirecting to home page
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

and route.php :

```
Route::get('/social/login/redirect/{provider}', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider', 'as' => 'social.login']);
Route::get('/social/login/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Now when I try my domain: http://mydomain.me/social/login/redirect/facebook

return me:

```
http://mydomain.me/social/login/facebook?code=AQAl29aq2-rX9L5-9GmiIwqstR-ETC ETC ETC#_=_
```

and error:
[image]

What is the problem here?

I tried to change domain from null to 'mydomain.me' at session.php and also tried:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

This doesn't work again.

Answer (score 1):

1. What is your session driver set to? If it's array then this will not work. Can you confirm session's are fully working in your application.
2. It looks like your not getting the `state` query string back in `/social/login/facebook` can you confirm you can see the query string in the redirect URL (i.e. when you see the facebook login page)?
3. Also you should check your facebook app settings and check the callback URL matches your site.

Comment: you haven't answered any of my questions

Comment: 1. My basic login work good. 2. yes I see query string like .me/social/login/facebook?code=AQAl29aq2-rX9L5-9GmiIwqstR-ETC ETC ETC#_=_ 3. fb app is ok, everything is set as usual... the same code on other app works good

Comment: you have not read number 2 carefully enough, that has not answered it.